# Stata "Regress" Command and Finding Average Difference

Tags: regression, self-study, stata, mean

I want to determine the average difference between 1998 treatment schools (group1=1) and  comparison schools (group1=0) in the following two characteristics:Proportion of female  children(“female”),Average child year of birth (“yob”)

I am new to Stata, so I don’t know what to type in the command window. What should I type? I've learned how to calculate the regression between an x and y variable where it's like

```
regress y x
```

but I don't know how to calculate regression between group 1 and the comparison group when compared to another characteristic. I need 2 regressions, so would set would I type?

```
regress group1=1 yob female
regress group1=0 yob female

regress group1=0 group2 yob
regress group1=1 group2 female
```

or something else?

and is the average difference given to me or is that something I need to calculate on my own?

All I know is that I have to use the `regress` command.

Here is the data set:

```
schid   group1  group2  group3  part98  female  yob
115 1   0   0   .7439648    .3834144    1987.234
117 1   0   0   .7443243    .3705711    1986.428
142 1   0   0   .7687114    .3864889    1987.516
143 1   0   0   .699026 .3519214    1987.588
158 1   0   0   .5439946    .3648172    1987.836
165 1   0   0   .7515087    .3641604    1987.808
191 1   0   0   .6320185    .3460737    1987.057
206 1   0   0   .8539617    .3606257    1987.215
207 1   0   0   .8054298    .3759444    1986.204
210 1   0   0   .8510154    .3543401    1986.542
215 1   0   0   .6107619    .387303 1987.144
216 1   0   0   1   .4003763    1986.481
219 1   0   0   .8350134    .3801926    1986.603
220 1   0   0   .6586895    .3857815    1986.905
265 1   0   0   1   .3786209    1986.815
267 1   0   0   .9961755    .3797742    1986.82
268 1   0   0   .9998046    .3439624    1986.505
274 1   0   0   .9886107    .448456 1986.628
279 1   0   0   .9877396    .387717 1986.717
281 1   0   0   .994603 .4124718    1985.863
286 1   0   0   .9647818    .3563205    1986.472
288 1   0   0   .9494266    .3386317    1985.715
290 1   0   0   .9806792    .4015853    1986.362
296 1   0   0   .9931837    .4222261    1986.637
297 1   0   0   1   .3925168    1986.104
109 0   1   0   .7627826    .3316738    1986.306
116 0   1   0   .6412753    .3338825    1987.693
118 0   1   0   .5040858    .3230579    1986.826
119 0   1   0   .6373736    .3749958    1986.878
133 0   1   0   .5865115    .4493426    1988.716
134 0   1   0   .3969593    .4464827    1987.21
141 0   1   0   .619329 .3765736    1987.549
164 0   1   0   .7135595    .2955894    1987.438
166 0   1   0   .7807278    .3349105    1987.209
182 0   1   0   .6992276    .3615404    1987.088
183 0   1   0   .7401822    .3925673    1988.551
192 0   1   0   .5432901    .3736948    1987.006
203 0   1   0   .6527734    .3902833    1986.182
208 0   1   0   .6212902    .4109006    1986.253
221 0   1   0   .8271556    .9911665    1988.778
262 0   1   0   .9702736    .3943461    1987.15
263 0   1   0   .6658556    .413118 1987.252
264 0   1   0   .9434038    .3477578    1986.569
269 0   1   0   .9521447    .3844051    1986.523
273 0   1   0   .8159674    .4032201    1987.036
277 0   1   0   .74529  .4287328    1986.644
284 0   1   0   .943206 .334808 1987.396
289 0   1   0   .9922523    .3737274    1986.665
292 0   1   0   .992666 .421622 1986.812
293 0   1   0   .8902047    .4432617    1985.719
108 0   0   1   .6897349    .2809297    1986.995
140 0   0   1   .7615737    .3513303    1987.509
144 0   0   1   .585315 .3754444    1986.324
167 0   0   1   .5862138    .3253592    1987.472
168 0   0   1   .7034473    .3261905    1987.37
189 0   0   1   .5167804    .2934488    1986.522
190 0   0   1   .6437579    .2906108    1986.846
193 0   0   1   .8333147    .3409633    1986.912
201 0   0   1   .7961279    .4090333    1986.359
202 0   0   1   .8110762    .4032104    1986.049
205 0   0   1   .8138164    .4128731    1986.051
211 0   0   1   .9859384    .3808163    1985.383
212 0   0   1   .8145156    .4102123    1986.173
213 0   0   1   .9905288    .3850739    1985.755
218 0   0   1   .9398516    .3266357    1986.124
```

Comment: @cardinal You're right, but it seems to me the underlying problem is not just about Stata syntax: it's about how to make these comparisons in the first place. user20971, could you expand on the first paragraph? Perhaps showing a small example of your data would help. Also, that phrase "have to use the regress command" suggests you are just asking us to do your homework for you. We welcome homework questions--but they have to conform to guidance in our [faq]; please consult it and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I am puzzled at the thought of a command like `regress group1 group2 yob` because it indicates that you are distinguishing the groups with *two* fields, `group1` and `group2`. I would expect your dataset to include a field whose values distinguish the treatment from the control group.  This could be the source of some of your confusion and it's why I suggested you post a small example of the data you are working with.  At a minimum you should consult the `Stata` manual pages for `regress` so that you understand where the names of the dependent and independent variables should appear.

Comment: I added the data set. I think I am confused between how to treat the control and treatment. I edited the question for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a variable `group` that distinguishes the treatment and the comparison group. For example, `group` is equal to zero for the comparison group and one for the treatment group. If so, then the following will do it:

```
tabulate group, summarize(yob)
tabulate group, summarize(female)
```

From the output, you can then compare the average values of `yob` and `female` across the two groups.

If you really want to use `regress`, then the following will do it:

```
regress yob group
regress female group
```

Assuming the variable `group` is defined as above, in each regression the coefficient on `group` will give you the difference across groups of the average of the dependent variable (`yob` in the first regression and `female` in the second regression).

If you do not have a variable `group`, then you should provide more information on how your `group1` and `group2` are coded so that I can explain how to generate the `group` variable.

Comment: This helps a lot! However, when I try to input regress yob group into the command window it gives me an error? I'm pretty sure that my variable is defined as group

Comment: Looking at your dataset above, you do not have a variable called `group` in it. Stata will return an error because it cannot find the variable with that exact name. Given your stated objective of comparing the treatment group, for which you say that group1 = 1, to the control group, for which you say that group1 = 0, you should use the command `regress yob group1`. However let me add that you have three groups in your data so that group1 will be equal to zero both for observations in group 2 and for those in group 3. I am pointing this out because this was not clear in your original question.

Comment: Okay I think I get it. So does regress yob group1 give me the average difference when comparing group1 and the control? Or is something I calculate my self?

Comment: The coefficient, i.e. the _Coef._ column in the output of `regress` will indeed give you the average difference between group 1 and the comparison group. Let me reiterate though, as I stated earlier, that `regress` is an overkill here. Using `tabulate group1, summarize(yob)` gives you the mean in both groups and you can compute the difference among groups from its output.

Comment: Follow-up question is here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/50308/930.